# sql: many to many relationship join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I'm very new to SQL so if there are multiple possibilities I'd like to see them all (and hear which possibilities are better than others). I'm using sqlite3.

I have the following 3 tables: `user`, `channel`, `subscriptions`

user:

```
user_id    name
1          Johnny
2          Stacy
3          Allana
```

channel:

```
channel_id    channel_name
1             ESPN
2             Disney
```

subscriptions:

```
user_id    channel_id
1          1
2          2
3          1
3          2
```

What SQL command do I need to perform to get the following table? I basically want to see who is subscribed to which channels by names (so exactly what's laid out in the `subscriptions` table but mapping numbers to names based on the other tables).

```
user_id    channel_id
Johnny     ESPN
Stacy      Disney
Allana     ESPN
Allana     Disney
```

I've tried the following but I'm getting nothing in the return statement:

```
select user.name, channel.channel_name from user, channel, subs where user.user_id == subs.user_id and channel.channel_id == subs.channel_id
```

Comment: Well... what have you tried? I realize you're a beginner, but this something you can easily find information on (there are lots of getting-started tutorials which would show such queries). And... StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service. I suggest editing your question to show your query so far, along with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and let me know in case you face any difficulty.

```
select a.name,c.channel_name
from
user a
left join
subscriptions b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
left join
channel c
on b.channel_id = c.channel_id;
```

or  (in the format u asked in comments)

```
select u.name,c.channel_name
from
user u
left join
subscriptions s
on u.user_id = s.user_id
left join
channel c
on s.channel_id = c.channel_id;
```

Comment: It worked! Is there a way to do it starting the statement off like so: `select u.name, c.channel_name from user u, channel c`.....

Comment: yes you can name the tables as u,s,c instead of a,b,c . Have you understood or you want me to change  that for you?

Comment: Can you add it as a second statement below the first one? Want to keep the original there for reference

Comment: This statement isn't as intuitive as I had hoped. Is there another way to do it that's entirely different?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you are asking?

Comment: Is there another way to perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but try this:

`select
  u.name
  ,c.channel
from
  user_id u
  inner join subscriptions s
    on u.user_id=s.user_id
  inner join channel c
    on s.channel_id=c.channel_id`